# Change active tab in TabBarNavigator when user presses a button within a view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Just a heads up, I'm a UX designer learning React Native to make a prototype.

I'm trying to figure out how to change the active tab when a user taps a button within a view on a different tab.

For example, if you're on the home view and there's a button that a user clicks that takes them to the settings view, I would like the settings tab to show as the active bottom tab when the view renders.

I currently can get the app to navigate to the new view, but it will still show the Home tab as the active tab. Additionally, there shouldn't be a "Back" button in the header when navigating to one of the screens that's accessible via the bottom Tab navigation. I looked through the React Navigation 3.x documentation but couldn't find anything to address this use case.

Here's the code I'm using currently.

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.push("Settings");
        }}
      >{...} 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the bottom tab navigator make sure that you have your settings screen as part of that tab.

Also, instead of `push`, consider `navigate` as that is what the docs recommend doing now as of v3 and newer.

Ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});
```

Comment: Yes, I made sure that all of my screens are defined in the createBottomTabNavigator code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to decide if you want tabs on the bottom or top of your Android app. I opted to go for the bottom, and I have only icons, no text (I did this because icons with text on React Navigation on Android crowds horribly, but look fine on the iPhone). Here is some example code for you:

```
 import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

// Import Screens
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Screen1',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <MaterialIcons name='account-circle' size={26} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
    },
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Screen2',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Ionicons name='ios-time' size={26} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
    },
  },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',        // I don't want a NavBar at top
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',  // So your Android tabs go bottom
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red',  // Color of tab when pressed
      inactiveTintColor: '#b5b5b5', // Color of tab when not pressed
      showIcon: 'true', // Shows an icon for both iOS and Android
      showLabel: (Platform.OS !== 'android'), //No label for Android
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 11,
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff', // Makes Android tab bar white instead of standard blue
        height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 48 : 50 // I didn't use this in my app, so the numbers may be off. 
      }
    },
});
```

You are using `push` function. Which push another view in the navigation stack. You can use `replace` there to not add another view in the stack. Also Check out the tabs navigation there in docs.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the option to use "replace", however even with swapping 'navigate' for 'replace' this still doesn't solve the issue of forcing a tab in the tab navigator to be active when navigating from an "onPress" action. I am using the createBottomTabNavigator though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings");
    }}
>{...} 
</TouchableOpacity>
```